# Violin Plot gaps are too large and need to be fixed

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

The gap between the two is too large in this picture. On the other hand, the [plotly sample code](https://plotly.com/python/violin/) has this gap smaller. How can we do this?

Diagram of my code
[image: Diagram of my code.]
[plotly sample code](https://plotly.com/python/violin/)
[image: plotly code]
my code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'one': [0.517970, 0.335520, 0.179993, 0.049795, -0.056827],
        'two': [0.457973, 0.283992, 0.136433, 0.013717, -0.085876]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['one'],
                        name='one',
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        opacity=1))

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['two'],
                        name='two',
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        opacity=1))

fig.show()
```

plotly sample code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.colors import n_colors
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# 12 sets of normal distributed random data, with increasing mean and standard deviation
data = (np.linspace(1, 2, 12)[:, np.newaxis] * np.random.randn(12, 200) +
            (np.arange(12) + 2 * np.random.random(12))[:, np.newaxis])

colors = n_colors('rgb(5, 200, 200)', 'rgb(200, 10, 10)', 12, colortype='rgb')

fig = go.Figure()
for data_line, color in zip(data, colors):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color))

fig.update_traces(orientation='h', side='positive', width=3, points=False)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, xaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Adjusting the height of the mountains will reduce the spacing. Try adding the following code from the sample code in the reference. `fig.update_traces(orientation='h', side='positive', width=5, points=False)`

Comment: Thank you. I would like to confirm one thing: if I use `width`, am I correct in understanding that the height of each figure is displayed in a normalised state so that it is a certain size?

Comment: Also, when two diagrams overlap, one comes under two, but this is different from the plotly sample code, so I want the one with the smallest number to come on top, as in the plotly sample code.

Comment: Is the drawing order shown on the figure to be placed in order from front to back? Are your sample and reference examples also drawn from front to back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a result that resembles the examples in the docs by adjusting the `width` attribute of the traces with, for example:

```
fig.update_traces(width = 4)
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'one': [0.517970, 0.335520, 0.179993, 0.049795, -0.056827],
        'two': [0.457973, 0.283992, 0.136433, 0.013717, -0.085876]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['one'],
                        name='one',
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        opacity=1))

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['two'],
                        name='two',
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        opacity=1))


fig.update_traces(width = 4)
fig.show()
```